# Style form elements in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have some Zend_Form

```
$text = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('text');
$text->setLabel('Leave a reply')
     ->setAttrib('rows', 9)
     ->setAttrib('cols', 50)
     ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
     ->setRequired(true)
     ->setAttrib('class', 'comment_form');
```

I wand to style this form, to add some style for label tag and another style for textarea tag.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify the decorators directly:

`$text->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('class', 'my-class-name');`

Or you can style the element appropriately using the generated ID as suggested by Mark. As a general rule if it needs to apply to more than a single form id do it the way i suggest to minimize the css length and add some clarity.

Comment: Didn't know you could do it this way. I would suggest this way instead of mine

Comment: Hello @prodigitalson, i've tried your solution, it just modify the ````label```` tag, not the ````dt```` so the text in label so long it will be overload under the input next to. is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

```
  $textarea = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea ('intro', array(
  'label' => 'Introduction',
  'attribs' => array ('style' => 'width: 100px'),
  ));
```

or if you have already got an element in $textarea

```
$textarea->setAttrib('style', 'width: 100px;');
```